# Using #pragma warning(push) and #pragma warning(pop) doesn't work as intended int his case

Tags: c++, visual-studio, warnings

I'm compiling at a high warning level and while I have no warnings in my code, I get tens of thousands from included headers.So to disable them I do this:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable : 4365)
#include <D3Dcommon.h>

#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3d11_1.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")

#include <d3dCompiler.h>
#include <D3D11Shader.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "D3DCompiler.lib")

#include <dxgiformat.h>
#include <dxgi.h>
#pragma warning(pop)
```

The problem is, I also have 5-6 disabled warnings in a header that is included everywhere in my code(for the entire project to see) and using the above pragmas for some reason enables them all back, giving me 150 thousand unwanted warnings all over the entire project.

The header with the 5-6 disabled warnings just lists them like this:(#### being different numbers)

```
#pragma warning(disable : ####)
#pragma warning(disable : ####)
#pragma warning(disable : ####)
#pragma warning(disable : ####)
......
```

I'm not using push or pop there, since I want them to be disabled everywhere.

Comment: First thing I would do is confirm this behavior in a little test program.  See if you can replicate it there.  If not, you'll at least know that something else is going on.

Comment: drop the push and replace the pop by #pragma warning(default : 4365)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are building with Visual C++ (Visual Studio) based on the code you posted.

Newer versions of Visual Studio allow you to set distinct C++ warning levels for external headers.  See [Customized Warning Levels and Code Analysis for External Headers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/customized-warning-levels-and-code-analysis-for-external-headers/)

So you can silence warnings from external headers (i.e. external libraries and the Windows SDK), while still having your own code be subject to whatever warning level you want.